# VBA Before close event

Tags: excel, vba

there is 2 events in my code i.e Before close,before save. in before save condition there are conditions to be filled before saving, else it wont allow to save. now while triggering before close, it will popup for save, dontsave, cancel message box. when selecting save, it will call before save function and it throws error message as like before save function. but after that file is closed.

```
    Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i misunderstood what u tried to describe , but take a look if my code below can help you.

```
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

        Select Case MsgBox("Select what do you want", vbYesNoCancel + vbExclamation, "Atention")
            Case vbYes
                Call Workbook_BeforeSave(True, False)
            Case vbNo
                Application.Quit
            Case vbCancel
                Cancel = True
        End Select

 Exit Sub
```

Comment: thanks it works, but following this default exit message popup window also comes and after doing the same thing it closes the file, that because of Cancel = true in Before save function